# VB Exception thrown when attempting 0^0?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

What exception does Visual Basic throw when attempting to raise 0 to the 0th power (0^0)? I'm using VS 2012.

Comment: Why do you ask this instead of testing it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Basic does not throw an exception.  `0^0` evaluates properly to `1`.

You can see the rules in the documentation of [`Math.Pow(x,y)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> `x = Any value except NaN; y = 0.` evaluates to a return value of `1`.

As a test, try:

```
Dim result = 0^0
Console.WriteLine(result)
```

This prints `1`.

Comment: Thanks! How unfortunate.

Comment: @user1505713 Why is that unfortunate?  This is very common with computations - most languages/frameworks evaluate this way.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Treatment_on_computers

Comment: That seems really dangerous. I think VB ought to complain about an indeterminate result.